# Impossible to retrieve data form pyattck module

Tags: python, python-3.10, mitre-attck

I am using the `pyattck` module to retrieve information from mitre att&ck.

Versions:

```bash
      - pyattck==7.0.0
      - pyattck-data==2.5.2
```

Then, I just created a simple `main.py` file to test the module.

```py
from pyattck import Attck

def main():
    attck = Attck()

    for technique in attck.enterprise.techniques:
        print(technique.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When running the `main.py` script I get the following exception:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/<path>/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    main()
  File "/<path>/main.py", line 8, in main
    for technique in attck.enterprise.techniques:
  File "/<path_venv>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyattck/attck.py", line 253, in enterprise
    from .enterprise import EnterpriseAttck
  File "/<path_venv>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyattck/enterprise.py", line 7, in <module>
    class EnterpriseAttck(Base):
  File "/<path_venv>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyattck/enterprise.py", line 42, in EnterpriseAttck
    __attck = MitreAttck(**Base.config.get_data("enterprise_attck_json"))
  File "/<path_venv>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyattck_data/attack.py", line 55, in __init__
    raise te
  File "/<path_venv>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyattck_data/attack.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.__attrs_init__(**kwargs)
  File "<attrs generated init pyattck_data.attack.MitreAttck>", line 14, in __attrs_init__
  File "/<path_venv>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyattck_data/attack.py", line 66, in __attrs_post_init__
    raise te
  File "/<path_venv>/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyattck_data/attack.py", line 62, in __attrs_post_init__
    data = TYPE_MAP.get(item['type'])(**item)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Anyone knows where is the issue? Maybe I have forgotten to import something? It would be helpful to know if this module actually works in another version. This one is the lasted stable one ATTOW.

**UPDATE**
There is am issue with this project. Mitre added some new features that are not supported by the module and make it unusable.

There is an [issue on github](https://github.com/swimlane/pyattck/issues/125)  related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have already fixed this issue in future releases. You just need to update your package `pyattck-data` form the bugged version `2.5.2` to `2.6.1` (or any newer).

If you are using pip, just run this:

```bash
pip install --upgrade pyattck-data
```

If you are using conda (inside your venv):

```bash
conda update pyattck-data
```